# Delete button Error jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have created a simple product inventory control form using query.

It consists of(product name, price, qty, amount) after filling all the fields and clicks add button all details it will append on the table row successfully.

After adding the price one by one, finally calculate and display the final total successfully.

I put the delete button next to the product.

Hitting `delete` button on particular row will be delete it successfully, but the final total amount didn't reduce once I delete the product from the product table.

I don't know how to reduce the price what I tried so far. i wrote it below. can anyone go through the code and give the good solution for it?

**Form**

```
         <tr>
                        <th>Product Code</th>
                        <th>Product Name</th>

                        <th>Price</th>
                        <th>Qty</th>
                        <th>Amount</th>
                        <th style="width: 40px">Option</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>

                        <td>

                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="barcode" id="barcode" name="barcode"  required>

                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <label id="pro_name" name="pname" id="pname"></label>
                            <input  type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="barcode" id="pname" name="pname"  >
                        </td>

                        <td>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control pro_price" id="pro_price" name="pro_price"
                                   placeholder="price" >
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="number" class="form-control pro_price" id="qty" name="qty"
                                   placeholder="qty" min="1" value="1"  required>
                        </td>


                        <td>
                            <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="total_cost" id="total_cost" name="total_cost">
                        </td>

                        <td>

                            <button class="btn btn-success" type="button" onclick="addproduct()">Add
                            </button>

                        </td>
  <table class="table table-bordered" id="product_list">
            <caption> Products</caption>
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th style="width: 40px">Remove</th>

                <th>Product Code</th>
                <th>Product Name</th>
                <th>Unit price</th>
                <th>Qty</th>
                <th>Amount</th>
            </tr>

            </thead>

            <tbody></tbody>

        </table>
```

**Final total**

```
<div class="form-group" align="left">
                <label class="form-label">Total</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Total" id="total" name="total" size="30px" required="">
            </div>
```

**JQuery**

```
<script>
 function addproduct() {
        var product = {
            barcode: $("#barcode").val(),
            pname: $("#pname").val(),
            pro_price: $("#pro_price").val(),
            qty: $("#qty").val(),
            total_cost: $("#total_cost").val(),
            button: '<button  type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs")">delete</button>'
        };
        addRow(product);
        ///$('#frmProject')[0].reset();
    }
    var total=0;
    function addRow(product) {
        console.log(product.total_cost);
        var $tableB = $('#product_list tbody');
        var $row = $("<tr><td><Button type='button' name = 'record'  class='btn btn-warning btn-xs' name='record' onclick='deleterow(this)' >Delete</td>" +
        "<td>" + product.barcode + "</td><td class=\"price\">" + product.pname + "</td><td>" + product.pro_price + "</td><td>" + product.qty + "</td><td>" + product.total_cost + "</td></tr>");
        $row.data("barcode", product.product_code);
        $row.data("pname", product.product_name);
        $row.data("pro_price", product.price);
        $row.data("qty", product.qty);
        $row.data("total_cost", product.total_cost);
        total += Number(product.total_cost);
        $('#total').val(total);
        console.log(product.total_cost);
        $row.find('deleterow').click(function(event) {
            deleteRow($(event.currentTarget).parent('tr'));
        });
        $tableB.append($row);
        onRowAdded($row);
    }
    function deleterow(e)
    {
        e.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(e.parentNode.parentNode);
        total -= Number(product.total_cost);
        $('#total').val(total);
    }
    function deleteRow(row) {
        console.log(product.total_cost);
        total -= Number(product.total_cost);
        $("#tot").val(tot);
        $(row).remove();
        onRowRemoved();
    }

    function updateTotal() {

    }

    function onRowAdded(row) {
        updateTotal();
    }

    function onRowRemoved(roe) {
        updateTotal();
    }


</script>
```

Comment: You should avoid defining two functions with identical names, but different case, it's confusing (see `deleterow` and `deleteRow`). Also, you're not passing/resolving product in any of your delete functions, `product.total_cost` should throw a ReferenceError on the console.

Comment: can you write code sir it is much easy to understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe kike this:

```
   function deleterow(e){
       product_total_cost=parseInt($(e).parent().parent().find('td:last').text(),10);
       total-=product_total_cost;
       $('#total').val(total);
       $(e).parent().parent().remove();
    }
```

```js
 function addproduct() {
        var product = {
            barcode: $("#barcode").val(),
            pname: $("#pname").val(),
            pro_price: $("#pro_price").val(),
            qty: $("#qty").val(),
            total_cost: $("#total_cost").val(),
            button: '<button  type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs")">delete</button>'
        };
        addRow(product);
        ///$('#frmProject')[0].reset();
    }
    var total=0;
    function addRow(product) {
        console.log(product.total_cost);
        var $tableB = $('#product_list tbody');
        var $row = $("<tr><td><Button type='button' name = 'record'  class='btn btn-warning btn-xs' name='record' onclick='deleterow(this)' >Delete</td>" +
        "<td>" + product.barcode + "</td><td class=\"price\">" + product.pname + "</td><td>" + product.pro_price + "</td><td>" + product.qty + "</td><td>" + product.total_cost + "</td></tr>");
        $row.data("barcode", product.product_code);
        $row.data("pname", product.product_name);
        $row.data("pro_price", product.price);
        $row.data("qty", product.qty);
        $row.data("total_cost", product.total_cost);
        total += Number(product.total_cost);
        $('#total').val(total);
        console.log(product.total_cost);
        $row.find('deleterow').click(function(event) {
            deleteRow($(event.currentTarget).parent('tr'));
        });
        $tableB.append($row);
        onRowAdded($row);
    }
    function deleterow(e){
       product_total_cost=parseInt($(e).parent().parent().find('td:last').text(),10);
       total-=product_total_cost;
       $('#total').val(total);
       $(e).parent().parent().remove();
    }
    function deleteRow(row) {

        console.log(product.total_cost);
        total -= Number(product.total_cost);
        $("#tot").val(tot);
        $(row).remove();
        onRowRemoved();
    }

    function updateTotal() {

    }

    function onRowAdded(row) {
        updateTotal();
    }

    function onRowRemoved(roe) {
        updateTotal();
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


         <tr>
                        <th>Product Code</th>
                        <th>Product Name</th>

                        <th>Price</th>
                        <th>Qty</th>
                        <th>Amount</th>
                        <th style="width: 40px">Option</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>

                        <td>

                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="barcode" id="barcode" name="barcode"  required>

                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <label id="pro_name" name="pname" id="pname"></label>
                            <input  type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="barcode" id="pname" name="pname"  >
                        </td>

                        <td>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control pro_price" id="pro_price" name="pro_price"
                                   placeholder="price" >
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="number" class="form-control pro_price" id="qty" name="qty"
                                   placeholder="qty" min="1" value="1"  required>
                        </td>


                        <td>
                            <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="total_cost" id="total_cost" name="total_cost">
                        </td>

                        <td>

                            <button class="btn btn-success" type="button" onclick="addproduct()">Add
                            </button>

                        </td>
  <table class="table table-bordered" id="product_list">
            <caption> Products</caption>
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th style="width: 40px">Remove</th>

                <th>Product Code</th>
                <th>Product Name</th>
                <th>Unit price</th>
                <th>Qty</th>
                <th>Amount</th>
            </tr>

            </thead>

            <tbody></tbody>

        </table>

Final total

<div class="form-group" align="left">
                <label class="form-label">Total</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Total" id="total" name="total" size="30px" required="">
            </div>
```

Comment: thanks for your great work sir. and again one help how to print the above items sir small recept need how to do this

Comment: Maybe `window.print();`  or `$(_SELECTOR_).print();`

Comment: How to write code sir write code it is much help ful for me thanks again

Comment: windows print need

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answer Brian Patterson gave you. Try replacing `#tot` with `#total` in the query selector. There is no `#tot` element in your html.

```
function deleteRow(row) {
    console.log(product.total_cost);
    var total = $("#total").val(); //grab current total from html element
    total -= Number(product.total_cost);
    $("#total").val(total);
    $(row).remove();
    onRowRemoved();
}
```

Comment: oversight on my part.  ill give ya an upvote just cuz you have no rep tho.  :)

Comment: sir. still not reduce it.i just check it sir thanks

Comment: thanks for your great work sir. and again one help how to print the above items sir small print receipt need how to do this

Comment: Thanks Brian. @GowryKanth DYOR: first google hit: https://github.com/DoersGuild/jQuery.print stackoverflow is not a code writing service.

Answer (score 0):

Your function does not have access to the total variable, grab it from html element `#total` ...

```
function deleteRow(row) {
        console.log(product.total_cost);
        var total = $("#total").val(); //grab current total from html element
        total -= Number(product.total_cost);
        $("#total").val(total);
        $(row).remove();
        onRowRemoved();
    }
```

Comment: still not reduce the final total. once i deleted

Comment: sorry, try with the edit i just made...   (your code is messy AF)